# how to send 2-3 param's to Winform C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to send 2-3 param's to Winform C# program ?

for example: i'll send something like `MyProg.exe 10 20 "abc"`

and in my program i can receive those values

(i dont want to show MyProg.exe - it will work background)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open up your `Program.cs` which is the entry point of your application. The main method is the one that fires up your application and this is the entry method.

You need to modify it a bit by chaning:

`static void Main()` to something else that will allow you to send an `array` of elements.

Try changing it to:

`static void Main(string[] args)` and loop through args and see what you get.

You can see a bit more examples and explenations over here: [Access Command Line Arguments](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/cmdlineargs03212006232449pm/cmdlineargs.aspx).

There are good libraries which will help you out a bit to [parse](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx) these command line arguments aswell.

**Examples**

To give you a bit more information I put together an example on an alternative way as Kobi mentioned:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ParseCommnandLineArguments();
    }

    static void ParseCommnandLineArguments()
    {
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        foreach(var arg in args)
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

`CommandLineArguments.exe -q a -b r`

will then Output

> CommandLineArguments.exe
>
> -q
>
> a
>
> -b
>
> r

The same result would also be possible with this way

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var arg in args)
            Console.WriteLine(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: And don't forget `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` - you can access the arguments from anywhere, not just `main`.

Comment: True! That's in the "bit more examples and explenations" link ;)

Comment: Why would the four tokens get separated into only two arguments instead of four? All links provided suggest the whitespace is always a delimiter (except when using quotes).

Comment: @MEMark, whitespace is a delimiter, just wrong formatting when pasting the result into the editor.

Answer (score 3):

For that there is the

```
Main(params string[] args)
{
}
```

All the arguments you passed to the application are in the string array args. You can read them from there and react correspdonding.