# Hiding the console window when running a wpf app from console

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

I have a wpf window that needs to get command line parameters.
i've tried changing it's output type to console app -but than a console window is opened when i run the exe file.

how can i hide that window so that only the wpf window will show?
tnx

Comment: If you want to open WPF window then why you have changed the project type as Console ? change it to *Windows Application* and see.

Comment: i'll try it - can a window application get parameters through the command line?

Comment: if you want to pass argument to WPF window you could pass the argument as how you do with console and read it from within *OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)* of App.xaml.cs

Comment: @barakcaf yes of course

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send 2-3 param's to Winform C# program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871749/how-to-send-2-3-params-to-winform-c-sharp-program)

Comment: changing the output to windows application solved the problem!! tnx