# C# pass more file paths via command line args

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments

I have problem with passing arguments into my program. Example: there are some mp3 files in some folder. My program is set to be a default program. If I select only one file and double click it, everything works fine. The problem is with more than one selected file. When i select more files and enter them, it starts its onw instance of program for each selected file. Is there any possibility to pass them as string array via command line args?

Edit:

run only one instance of my program I use

```
        Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MKMusicPlayer");
        if (proc.Length > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Program is already running!");
            proc[1].Kill();

        }
```

and to get args

```
            if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1)
            {//code}
```

Comment: That's how windows works.  You'd have to make your application detect that an instance is already running and pass the argument to the running instance to achieve what you want.

Comment: In addition to the code how are you selecting files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send 2-3 param's to Winform C# program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871749/how-to-send-2-3-params-to-winform-c-sharp-program)

Comment: As far as I know a new default application instance will be run for each file you try to open, so I could only recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390829/is-it-possible-to-talk-with-running-process to allow only single instance that gets new file paths to process from its other execution attempts.

Comment: @juharr: it is already implemented. It detects running app with the same name and protect it to run again.

Comment: @kmcnamee: e.g. user select all files in folder and press enter, it runs my program for each selected file instead of passing them as args.

Comment: @mmaverikk  In that case you should show your code for making your application single-instance.  Also if you open one file and then another does it correctly pass the second file to the first instance and not open a second instance?

Comment: @juharr it always tries to open new instance. So how to prevent this behaving? How to pass this args to my running app?

Comment: @mmaverikk You can use a Mutex for making it single instance and Named Pipes for communication.  Check out the links in Eugene's comment.

Comment: @mmaverikk I have already given to you [links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010537/c-sharp-pass-more-file-paths-via-command-line-args#comment46266478_29010537) to the required information that will allow you to create a working solution. It is neither pretty nor simple, but short of changing how OS handles default program it is probably the only real option. Perhaps there is already some finished solution that uses such approach but you will have to search for it.